# Need an understanding on deque

Tags: c++, deque

I do not understand how for d[5] the answer is C. I am trying to understand lists in C++ but for some reason this concept escapes me. Can anyone explain why C is the correct answer?

```
The following represents output from the call d.Dump() from the

fsu::Deque<char> object d:

content_[i]: A B C D E F G H I J

i mod 10:    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

                   e       b


 What is the result of the output statement



std::cout << d[5];?
```

Comment: I'm finding it quite hard to understand your question. Can you please post some code we can test ourselves, in the form of an [mcve]. Be sure to include the actual output, and the output you expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If b stands for the beginning of the queue, count 5 steps to the right, jumping from 9 to 0. You end up at C.

Comment: How do I know that b stats for the beginning of the queue?

Comment: I think the output you see should be explained in your notes. If not, it's not hard to guess.

Comment: you think it would be but it is not

Comment: I'd say experience. How would you implement a deque using an array without having to copy all the values around all the time? You leave the elements at place and move begin and end of the queue instead. Having this in mind, it gets almost obvious what `b` and `e` have to stand for...

Comment: I do not have much experience in this and I tend to over think some basic things.

Comment: Imagine you have the buffer as provided above. How would you add another element at the beginning (push_front)? You decrement b by one and insert at this location (example: 6) the new element. At the end? Depends, if e is pointing to the last element or one element after (as all the `end()` iterators of the STL do). Former case: increment e, place element at new location; latter case: *first* place element at position e, then increment (incrementing and decrementing always modulo current capacity). Removing elements is the other way round.

Comment: I left some special cases yet unconsidered that would have to be handled explicitly: removing from and empty queue and inserting into an already full queue... Unfortunately, the question is locked already, else I could have provided you a code example for understanding.